# iOS AsyncSocket same as Android http request

Tags: android, ios

I am writing an app for iPad that responses to Android http request.
This is the piece of code for client Android:

```
HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(URLName);
String re = client.execute(httpPost);

String temp = re;

if(temp.equals("")) {
    return false;               
} else if (temp.length() > 10) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

This is instead the part of code to AsyncSocket

```
- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)socket didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag {   
    NSString *tmp = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
    NSString *encode = [self convertiInJson:tmp];

    [socket writeData:[encode dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] 
          withTimeout:1 
                  tag:HTTP_HEADERS];

    NSLog(@"Utenti %@",encode);
    [socket disconnectAfterWriting];
}
```

I receive the request and I send the JSON response but Android doesn't receive anything because it receives a protocol exception when client executes request.

Comment: So what exactly are you asking? Which code is working well now - the iOS one? And you want to make the Android code behave the same way?

Comment: my problem is this when i send request from android ipad receive correctly and when ipad send response android don't receive nothing because i have an protocol exeption in metod client execute.I want to receive in android the data that i send with ipad. Android work well if the web server is apache.I have understand only how android want the response.

Comment: Did you try from a desktop client? What happens on desktop?

Comment: Can you upload your implementation of convertiInJson method.

Comment: Why you've decided to use AsyncSocket? That choice forces you to implement all HTTP protocol handling by yourself. Try some ready-to-use iOS web-server instead, like this: https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer

Comment: I think you are using 'WebSocket' on android and 'AsyncSocket' on iOS. Try using this websocket from facebook, i think this will work for you: https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket